# Code table and Hibernate JPA mapping

Tags: hibernate

Say I have code table in DB - Product_Type with N possible values and Product table with one of the attribute as Product_Type (FK).

What is the recommended way of using JPA to map Product_Type in Product table to the code table?

Comment: A ManyToOne association. Each product has a type. Several products have the same type. That's a ManyToOne.

Answer (score 1):

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PRODUCT")
public class Product {

    @Id
    private long productId;

    @ManyToOne()
    private ProductType productType;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "PRODUCT_TYPE") 
public class Product_Type {

   @Id
   private long product_type_id;

}
```

Comment: Please check class names - ProductType versus Product_Type - is this intentional?